# Email reset password not working, however account confirmation works .NetCore

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

So I followed the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

My application works and sends out an account confirmation email using the Email service I set up.

However if I go to reset password, the identity service does not call the email service to send the email instructions. What am I doing wrong?

How can the identity service know how to use email to confirm account but can't use it to reset password?

For context

```
 startup.cs


 // requires
 services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
 services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);


 EmailSender.cs

public class EmailSender:IEmailSender
{
    public EmailSender(IOptions<AuthMessageSenderOptions> optionsAccessor)
    {
        Options = optionsAccessor.Value;
    }

    public AuthMessageSenderOptions Options { get; } //set only via Secret Manager

    public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        return Execute(Options.SendGridKey, subject, message, email);
    }

    public Task Execute(string apiKey, string subject, string message, string email)
    {
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var msg = new SendGridMessage()
        {
            From = new EmailAddress("stackoverflow@blah.com", Options.SendGridUser),
            Subject = subject,
            PlainTextContent = message,
            HtmlContent = message
        };
        msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));

        // Disable click tracking.
        // See https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/tracking.html
        msg.SetClickTracking(false, false);

        return client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ran into the same issue and discovered that while registration emails were being sent, password reset emails were not. In our case, it was because of two issues with the `AspNetUsers` table:

1. We didn't complete the email confirmation step, which sets the `EmailConfirmed` bool in the database to `True`, and
2. We had migrated the data over from an earlier version of ASP.NET Core where the two email fields, `Email` and `NormalizedEmail` were not set and were left `null`.

Once we populated the missing email fields, and ran the confirmation step—or manually changed the flag to `True`—the password reset emails started working.